# GCP: Added as an owner of client's organization, but it's not showing in my account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

A client added myself and another person as an owner of their organization in their Google Cloud account. They sent a screenshot of the organization's principals and we are definitely in there and the email addresses are correct. However, when I view my organizations, it's not listed. We didn't receive an email letting us know we were added to their organization, so I'm assuming we don't need to approve it, but why is the organization not showing? Does our client need to create a project before we can even see the organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be an `Owner` of a Google Cloud project, you must accept Google Cloud's Terms of Service (TOS) via a link sent to you in an email.

If you did not receive the email, you have an email problem to solve. Check the obvious such as the SPAM folder. If you do not manage your domain's email server, contact your vendor.

Comment: Thanks! We'll look into what could be causing the email issue. Our email is with Google as well, so it's strange we wouldn't be receiving emails.

Comment: Oh, something I just realized. You said "To be an Owner of a Google Cloud project" but there is no project yet. We were added as an Owner of an organization, not a project. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Gavin - yes. ORGs are managed differently than standalone projects. That includes legal matters such as ownership and contract acceptance.